# Tag wiki excerpt edit link triggers page not found error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

While trying to edit a tag wiki excerpt, I encountered the page not found issue.

Here are the steps that I performed:

1. Clicked on **Tags**
2. Clicked on the **name** tab
3. Clicked edit link under the tag [.ajax](/questions/tagged/.ajax). Refer screenshot **#1**.
4. Encountered the Page not found error message. Refer screenshot **#2**.
5. I thought that error must have to do with the period (dot) in the tag name. So, I tried to edit the tag [.app](/questions/tagged/.app) and I didn't encounter any error message. Refer screenshot **#3**.
6. When I clicked the tag [.ajax](/questions/tagged/.ajax), the browser URI looked as shown in screenshot **#4**. The id value is being passed as -1.
7. When I clicked the tag [.app](/questions/tagged/.app), the browser URI looked as shown in screenshot **#5**.

It seems that the error happens to tags that don't have any questions. [.avi](/questions/tagged/.avi), [.bat](/questions/tagged/.bat) are some of the tags that have the same issue. The error happens only while clicking the edit link on the page shown in screenshot **#1**. Even though tags page doesn't show any count against these tags, clicking on the tags leads to a page with full of questions but on closer inspection they seem to lead to a slightly altered version of the tag.

[.ajax](/questions/tagged/.ajax) leads to tag ajax without a period (dot)

[.avi](/questions/tagged/.avi) leads to tag avi without a period (dot)

[.bat](/questions/tagged/.bat) leads to tag batch-file

**Screenshots:**

**#1:** Steps to click tag wiki excerpt link

[image: Steps]

**#2:** Page not found error while editing tag .ajax

[image: Page not found]

**#3:** No error while editing tag .ajax

[image: No error]

**#4:** Edit uri for tag .ajax

[image: tag .ajax]

**#5:** Edit uri for tag .app

[image: tag .app]

Comment: I don't believe the problem is the links; the problem is that the tags showing up on that page are invalid, which are then generating the invalid links. If you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.csv you get redirected to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv which is correct. Note that there is a tag wiki for `[ajax]`, but it doesn't show up under `[.ajax]`.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Yes, as you said that the tags may be invalid. In that case, I believe those invalid tags shouldn't be displayed on that page. I have also pointed that out in my question that the tags with dot actually lead to tag without dot.

Comment: I really like how your bug reports include repro screenshots. Whatever development team you work on must really love-hate you.

Comment: @Cody What, no complaint that the arrows look suspiciously straight? Siva: the common factor is that those tags are synonyms; the `edit` link is wrong for synonyms (you can reproduce with e.g. [tag:shellscript] which is a synonym of [tag:shell]).

Comment: @Siva The comment to Cody was a semi-private joke, a reference to his comments that [my](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97243) [circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98662) aren't hand-drawn. I don't understand your comment about suggesting synonyms of ssis; what I'm saying is that the bug isn't related to the initial `.` but to the fact that the tags are synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just *fixed* this particular bug.

I now remove the edit link from tag synonyms. This issue only happened when the `/tags` page shows a synonym and you try to edit it.

I think the way we handle tag synonyms in the `/tags` page needs some extra TLC, we should make it crystal clear you are dealing with a synonym, that way it teaches people what the right tag is. Also it should be consistent with the new tagger.