# Flagged comment on question that got deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderator-tools, flags

How are flags for comments on deleted questions handled?  Do they show up on mod queues?  In my particular case I flagged a question comment and before it was addressed the question was deleted by 3 20K+ users.  The flag has not been cleared yet so I was just wondering if it's now dangling or if a mod will still see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment flags no longer show up in the mod queue if the post containing the flagged comments is deleted.