# Do custom flags remain on deleted posts?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-posts, age

I occasionally see suspected [underage users](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age) posting. Usually these posts get deleted for unrelated issues (if someone's stating their age, they're probably not writing very useful content either).

I flag these with a custom reason, so the account can be blocked, or whatever the appropriate action is. I have a concern that (especially with the current reduced moderator activity) the flag may not be seen before the post is deleted.

Will a moderator still see them, or should I escalate ToS/welfare concerns in some other way?

---

Same question on MSO: [Are flags still reviewed if the post is deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284459/476716)

The answer here has good advice for my specific issue though.

Comment: Related, but antique: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98662/please-clear-flags-on-post-deletion But from my time as a mod ages ago, but still sooner than that post, I think there was least one time a flag wasn't cleared on a deleted post.

Comment: custom flags never gets cleared automatically when a post gets deleted, AFAIK.

Comment: @rene what if it's a custom flag on a comment?

Comment: @OrangeDog Custom flags on comments also count for the auto deletion for comments and are marked helpful when that happens. Not sure if they're marked helpful when they're not the flag to cause the auto deletion.

Comment: Recent example [post from a 10 year old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336915/282094) made a few minutes ago. Closed OT, when it was a site referral request.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I wasn't aware of an age requirement for posting.  Does "underage" refer to a specified minimum age, or is that a generic reference to youngsters who don't yet have enough background to be able to contribute posts that are useful and of acceptable quality?

Comment: @fixer1234 https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike other flags (spam, rude/abusive, very low quality, not an answer, off-topic), which are marked helpful when the corresponding post is deleted, [custom moderator flags aren't resolved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284462/4751173) and will still be pending (and eventually reviewed by a ♦ moderator).

> Yes, any active flag will still show to moderators whether the post is deleted or not. Custom flags can sometimes contain information that warrants further moderator action than *just* post deletion, so they do not ever get automatically cleared with a non-moderator post deletion.

Because ♦ moderators have no option to deal with underage users, other than to escalate the issue to the Community Team, it might be even better just to use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form to report underage users. That way you'll reach them directly.

Comment: Would that be the "Other" option, or does it count as "Code of Conduct violation"?

Comment: I'd choose 'Other', the Code of Conduct is more for users harassing one another.